# Deploy to Amazon EC2 from Cloudbees

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloudbees

Is it possible to set up Cloudbees to deploy to an Amazon EC2 instance after a successful build?

Thanks,
W

Comment: were you able to successfully deploy your app to EC2 after a Jenkins build?  would like some details of how you got it working

Comment: hi.. i haven't got this far yet..i was thinking ahead...i'm still manually copying and deploying files

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you don't provide many details of what you mean by "deploy".  I suppose you mean using scp?  If so, you must copy your [Jenkins public key](https://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/How+to+use+Private+GitHub+Repositories+with+CloudBees) to an authorized keys file, and make sure that your [security group rules](https://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Allowing+Access+to+EC2+Resources+From+CloudBees+Slaves) allow CloudBees' build machines to talk to your EC2 instance.

Comment: Hi,Sorry for being vague!..  What I meant was 'deploy' as in continuous deployment style. After a successful Jenkins build, the .ear file would be auto deployed to a running JBoss on a EC2 instance (replacing an old version) -- perhaps as Jenkins post build step?

I suppose option b) might be to write a script that would be manually run after a successful build to do the same

Thanks for the reply,
W